# Using a global store (or not) with extjs

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, store

In my Extjs5 MVC application, I maintain several stores over the same data:

- One store for a left navigation tree of my app
- One store for a global representation of my data
- etc

Each store executes the *same* request to the server to fetch the *same* data which forces me to make a complicated events system to tell other stores to reload themselves when I modify something somewhere.
Would it be a better practice to have a global (singleton?) store for the whole application?

Comment: Chain stores may be helpful. Anyway personally i dont prefer singleton stores.

Comment: Why are different stores receiving the same data? You should consider split your data over multiple stores with different server endpoints (e.g. per model).

Comment: because I display the same data on a tree, on a HTML panel, etc.

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej thanks, chained store seem to be exactly what I need: http://extjs.eu/on-chained-stores/